# Use Partition By to return the MAX record from Join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, max, partitioning

I am trying to use and learn Partition By to return the max step number of a one-to-many relationship. 
Basically, I have one companyID, which is unique in company table. The company has certain steps, which can be however many in the StepCompany table. The companID exists for every step there may exist for that company in the stepCompany table. The steps have StepOrder, which is what I need to use to always return the MAX of those. But I need one single query to return both information from the company and stepCompany based on which step is basically the last step in that company’s queue. 
Sources I find I either do not understand since I am new to Partition By, or they give the Partition By an alias, and at the end of the outer select, they do like the alias = 1 for example.
Here is the query return with no partition by or anything.

```
CompanyIDticketID|||| companyCompanyID||| stepCompanyCompanyID|||| stepCompanyStepOrder
----------------- ---------------- -------------------- --------------------
136211     ||||       10B7E005     |||    10B7E005      |||       1

136211     ||||       10B7E005     |||    10B7E005      |||       2

136211     ||||       10B7E005     |||    10B7E005      |||       3

155585     ||||       3A2078C5     |||    3A2078C5      |||       1

155585     ||||      3A2078C5      |||   3A2078C5       |||       2

193256     ||||       95AC74FB     |||    95AC74FB      |||       1

193256     ||||       95AC74FB     |||    95AC74FB      |||       2

210425     ||||       0BAD0261     |||    0BAD0261      |||       1

210425     ||||       0BAD0261     |||    0BAD0261      |||       2
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, not sure how to create a table neatly here.

So these are 2 table being joined. companyCompanyID = stepCompanyCompanyID is used to join them. So for companyID 136211 I need stepCompanyStepOrder 3 to return, obviously with data in the stepCompany table. For companyIDticketID 155585 I need the stepCompanyStepOrder 2, etc. 
I'd rather not provide my SQL as it's not pretty:)

I appreciate everyone's help!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the partial query,

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  ....,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyIDticketID
                               ORDER BY stepCompanyStepOrder DESC) rn
    FROM    ....
)
SELECT  *
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

You just need to plugin your join query inside the `WITH` clause and add extra column which partition the records.

Comment: sweeeeeeeeeeeeeet! I guess having that rn=1 that I found in other sources as well was the way...I just didn't understand the concept..that was easy..thanks a lot JW!

Comment: remove `WHERE   rn = 1` and see what happens in column `RN` `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Without the join since you haven't provided it, but it should not matter:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT rn = Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       partition BY companycompanyid 
                       ORDER BY stepcompanysteporder DESC), 
                companyidticketid, 
                companycompanyid, 
                stepcompanycompanyid, 
                stepcompanysteporder 
         FROM   dbo.tablename) 
SELECT companyidticketid, 
       companycompanyid, 
       stepcompanycompanyid], 
       stepcompanysteporder 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f248/1/0)

Result:

```
COMPANYIDTICKETID   COMPANYCOMPANYID    STEPCOMPANYCOMPANYID    STEPCOMPANYSTEPORDER
210425          0BAD0261            0BAD0261                    2
136211          10B7E005            10B7E005                    3
155585          3A2078C5            3A2078C5                    2
193256          95AC74FB            95AC74FB                    2
```

Comment: thanks Tim, JW beat you to it, but I realized I just didn't understand the concept of having that rn=1 at the end...I don't know what i thought before now that I understand the concept..lol..thanks Tim!